# How to skip ui-router's ui-view and redirect partial url without .html extension in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

On trying to navigate from Home page using the below, it redirects me to a page with `.html` extension.

```
<a href="playplug.html"></a>

/example.com/playplug.html
```

How to actually skip using the .html extension in URL for the partial template as shown below with/without using `ui-view`, **cos, I want to navigate to a separate HTML page and no need to display the partial template inside home_page (example.com)**.

```
/example.com/playplug
```

Normally, the ui-router's ui-view let me display the partial template inside the main page; Is there something like this to override ui-router's ui-view or any other tweak... am new to AngularJS

```
<a href="playplug.html" url="/playplug"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is just put the full URL. That works most of the times.

See example here:
https://github.com/reflexdemon/ng-gulp/blob/master/src/app/home/home.html#L4

See Demo here:
http://demo-venkatvp.rhcloud.com/#/home

Comment: Hi! it's not an external url; i have to redirect to the partial template that I own inside the project.